# error: package directory 'Operaciones\defOperacion' does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, modulos

Lo que pasa es que estoy aprendiendo recientemente a programar, y todo bien hasta ahí pero cuando quiero ejecutar un paquete distribuible en el CMD: `py setup.py sdist`
Me aparece este error:

```
error: package directory 'Operaciones\defOperacion' does not exist
```

Los módulos si existen pero sigo teniendo ese error y me estoy comiendo la cabeza por eso

Tengo Python 3.8.3 y uso PyCharm